# Removing id/variable from SEO friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo, friendly-url

I am trying to rewrite a URL so that it is SEO friendly and excludes the product ID. Currently I am using this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/product/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ products.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC,L]
```

For example rewrites it to:

```
shop/product/product-name/12
```

Is there a way that I can rewrite this URL so it **removes** or excludes the product ID from the end?

Comment: Could you please do be clear from which URL(in browser) to which URL in backend you want to serve in your question for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you meant like someone hits `shop/product/product-name/12` url in browser it should be seen as `shop/product/product-name/` but should be served from `products.php`(with query string passed to it)?

Comment: That's right. When someone hits `shop/product/product-name/12` it should be seen as `shop/product/product-name/`. The content is served on `products.php` with a query string passed to it (where it grabs product data, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

First set of Rules is considering that your product.php is present in root, in same path as .htaccess is present.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^shop/product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /products.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NE,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/products\.php\?id=[^&]*&name=[^\s]*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ shop/product [R=301,QSD,NE,L]
```

---

---

***OR*** Please use either above OR following rules at a time only in your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^shop/product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ products.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NE,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} products\.php\?id=[^&]*&name=[^\s]*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ shop/product [R=301,QSD,NE,L]
```

Comment: I tried the code in my .htaccess file (products.php is in the root along with the .htaccess file), but it keeps trying to navigate to the root of my server structure instead:

`https://www.domain.co.uk/mnt/storage/vhosts/plesk-subscription.co.uk/domain.co.uk/shop/product`

Comment: @LHolden, could you please try my OR solution once and let me know if that helps you?